Can I write this asymptotic expansion?
Suppose I have
$$
f(x)=e^{-x}g(x)+h(x)
$$
where I know that $h(x)\to k$ as $x\to 0$.
Can I write the following?
$$
f(x)=g(x)+k+o(1)
$$
as $x\to 0$.

False. For example, if $h(x)=0, k=0$ and $g(x)=\frac 1 x$ then $f(x)-g(x)-k \to -1$ as $ x \to 0$.
Your last line is not valid. Behavior of $g(x)$ near $0$ comes into the picture.
However, the conclusion holds if $g$ is bounded in some interval around $0$.

Why $f(x)-g(x)-k\to-1$?

Because $\frac {e^{-x}-1} x \to -1$ as $x \to 0$ (by L'Hopital's Rule, or by series expansion). @MrFrog

This suggests we have error bounds depending on the shape of $g(x)$. In my case $g(x)=x^{-a}$ where $a\in(0,2)$. Numerically it works for $a<1$.

Yes, it does work for $a<1$ because $x(x^{-a})\to 0$ as $x \to 0$. @MrFrog

what rule are you implicitly using?

For $x^{-a}$ there would be a problem with the definition for $x<0$. You can only take the right hand limit. For right hand limit I am suing that fact that $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^{b}=0$ for $b>0$. (Take $b=1-a$).
